# Rule of thumb when drawing N samples from a discrete distribution with N possible values with replacement

Tags: discrete-data, rule-of-thumb

I'm looking for an explanation and possibly the name of a rule of thumb:

When drawing N samples with replacement from a discrete uniform distribution of N values, it is very likely that:

- 1/3 of the values are not drawn
- 1/3 of the values are drawn exactly once
- 1/3 of the values are drawn more than once

The way I heard that was with throwing 64 pieces of rice onto a chess board and then observing roughly what I described above. I'm seeing this very often, but I want to read up on the theory and calculations behind it.

Why is this rule of thumb valid and does this rule of thumb have a name? And if yes, which one?

Comment: I know of no name for this, but it is a straightforward consequence of a simple argument: to a good approximation, especially for large $N$ (say, $N\ge 20$), the number of times each value is drawn has a Poisson$(1)$ distribution.  This assigns probability $1/e$ to each of $0$ and $1$ and (therefore) $1-2/e$ to all other values.  Your rule of thumb replaces $e\approx 2.72$ by $3$.  This rule actually *worsens* the approximation, especially for smaller $N$. A similar analysis predicts frequencies for drawing $M\ne N$ samples without replacement.

Comment: @whuber: Make that an answer, this is a very good explanation of the phenomenon. I'll change the question to put more emphasis on the theory than the name.

Comment: @whuber I've found it, it's called the "law of small numbers". I found it thanks to your hint with the Poisson distribution. I'll make an answer for it but won't mark it correct, you deserve the credit ;)

Comment: @whuber Thx. I will just give it a few days, then accept it if nothing better appeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule is called ***law of small numbers*** and was described by [Ladislaus Bortkiewicz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladislaus_Bortkiewicz) (German: [*Gesetz der kleinen Zahlen*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesetz_der_kleinen_Zahlen) from Ladislaus von Bortkewitsch).

Credit goes to *whuber* for pointing me to the Poisson distribution. I'll leave it to him to provide a better answer.

In short: According to the Poisson distribution, the amount of object that get "hit" exactly $k$ times for $n \rightarrow \infty$ is

$$P(X=k) = {1 \over k!} e^{-1}$$

This means the amount of values that are never drawn ($k=0$) is ${1 \over e} \approx 36,7879 \%$ and the same for ($k=1$), which is approximately one third.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a rule, but it's much more precise than a rule of thumb. This type of problem is modeled by a [multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), and it actually models something even more general than what you have described: suppose that instead of drawing $N$ samples with replacement from a population of $N$ distinct values, you draw $n$ samples from a population of $k$ distinct values.  Thus, it even models the situation where the number of samples and the number of values aren't necessarily equal.